# Why is package manager ignoring the settings in the nuspec file

Tags: nuget-package, nuget-spec

From my understand the nuspec file this should not be adding anything from the plugins folder, but all the files are still being added.  I just want them in the pack, and not added to the project.

This is the file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>test</id>
    <version>4.9.0</version>
    <title>test</title>
    <authors>test</authors>
    <description>test</description>
    <releaseNotes>
    </releaseNotes>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="**" exclude="plugins/**" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="false" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="view\**" target="content\plugins\test\view" />
    <file src="readmes\**" target="content\plugins\test\readmes" />
    <file src="content\**" target="content\Themes\Default\test" />
  </files>
</package>
```

what am I missing?
thanks

I've tried what is there, and about 50 different variations to figure this out.

Thanks